# Any text search from JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery

I am filtering data from jQuery datatable.
Search is doing search from first letter only from the column
Search is not showing results from second word or any mid word.
I need the search where search contains any text from the column.
Help me with the solution

`dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();`

Complete code set is here.

```
$('.search-input-text').on( 'keyup click', function () {   // for text boxes
                       var i =$(this).attr('data-column');  // getting column index
                       var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
                       dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
                   } );
```

Please advise.

Comment: Partial matches are the default search method for Datatables. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/. Type 'count' in the search box, and 'Accountant' is returned. If this is not the behaviour you're seeing, then it's down to how you've configured the instance.

Comment: For me he want to type “one two three” and have all results contain one of the three words

Comment: Alternatively you can check for indexof in the string to perform search
  If(dataTable.columns(i).indexOf(v) >  -1)){
        dataTable.columns(i).draw();
    }